# Render fragment contents with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf, html-email

I'm tryting to have email templates rendered using Thymeleaf and I would like to have the subject and the body in the same file, but rendered separately. I do not want to use spring view, just plain `SpringTemplateEngine`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<!--/*@thymesVar id="user" type="com.myapp.user.User"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="invitationId" type="java.util.UUID"*/-->
<head>
    <title th:fragment="subject">Hello <span th:text="${user.name}"/></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Hello <span th:text="${user.name}"></span>,<br>
    you've been invited to join MyApp.
</p>
<p>
    Click on the following link to confirm your email and setup a password:<br>
    <a th:href="@{https://myapp.com/accept-invitation(id=${invitationId})}">Accept invitation</a>
</p>
<p>
    Best regards,<br/>
    <em>The MyApp team</em>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There are several problems with this

First, I'm unable to get Thymeleaf render only contents of `<title>`

```
String subject = templateEngine.process(
    templateFile,
    ImmutableSet.of("subject"),
    new Context(Locale.ENGLISH, contextVariables)
);
```

it renders literary only `Hello` - it looks like the opening `<title>` tag is always removed and the fragment is trimmer right after the first tag.

And when I render the whole template, it returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    Hello <span>pepa</span></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Hello <span>pepa</span>,<br>
...
```

Using the following in the `<title>` makes the output a bit nicer

```
<span th:text="${user.name}" th:remove="tag"></span>
```

but the opening tag is still missing.

When I would theoretically succeed in rendering the title correctly, I'd still have it wrapped in an HTML tag - which obviously cannot be used as an email subject. Is there a way to render only contents of the fragment?

I would really like to have both the email subject and body in the same template for cases, when for example I want to do some iteration in the title to generate it from a list - I do not want to do any string concatenations, I wanna have it in the template.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to include only the content of your fragment, assuming that your fragment is called **your_fragment.html** and is placed under **/resources/templates/fragments** you can do:

```
<head>
  <title th:replace="fragments/your_fragment::your_fragment"/></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
```

And your_fragment.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="your_fragment" th:remove="tag">
      Hello <span th:text="${user.name}" th:remove="tag"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will render:

```
<head>
  Hello username
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you've understood my question, since this doesn't help me at all - and if it does, I don't see how.

Comment: I thought that you needed to render only text inside the <title> tag, the above code will render <title>Hello username</title>

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I need the string that it outputs use as an email subject and I cannot put `<title>` tags inside the subject. I know I can strip the tag, but it would be nicer, if thymeleaf could actually render the contents of the snippet, without the wrapper tag.

Comment: And if you try th:replace instead of t:include? 

Something like: `<title th:replace="fragments/your_fragment::your_fragment"/></title>`

I've updated the answer too